# How can I define a 'do_twice' function with using '*args'?

Tags: python

I've made a code to repete a function process:

```
def do_twice(func, *args):
    func(func(args))
def div(number):
    print(number[0]/2)
do_twice(div, 8)
```

The expected output is:

```
4.0
2.0
```

But the output is:

```
4.0
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

At this point I thought: Seems like `number` is `None` in the second round.
And my guess prooved as correct:

```
…
def div(number):
    print(number)                          # i know, actually i shouldn't call it div NOW...

# output:
4
None
```

What was my fault? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a few problems here - the first being that function `div` has no `return` statement. That is where the `NoneType` error is coming from - `div` is returning `None` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te problem is that when 'div' is called for the first time it gets args as input and it is looking for args[0]. The seconds call to 'div' will return a number and args[0] will fail.

Code below seems to work:

```
def do_twice(func, *args):
    return func(func(args))


def div(number):
    return number[0] / 2 if isinstance(number, tuple) else number / 2


print(do_twice(div, 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

It didn't take too many changes to fix.

```
def do_twice(func, *args):
    func(func(args[0]))
def div(number):
    result = number/2
    print(result)
    return result # Return the result
do_twice(div, 8)
```

`div` needs to `return` the result of its calculation in order for it to be stored by `do_twice` for the second iteration. Otherwise, your intuition is correct, you're dividing `None` on the second execution of `div`.

The key takeaway is:
Returning makes values accessible outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting to return something from the functions:

```
def do_twice(func, *args, **kwargs):
    return func(func(*args, **kwargs))

def div2(n):
    x = n / 2
    print(x)   # For debugging. A function like this normally would not print.
    return x

do_twice(div2, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the call `func(func(args))`, the function `func` does not return any value. Hence, `func(args)` doesn't provide the required `number` argument for `func` in the outer call

function `div` should be modified as follows

```py
def div(number):
    print(number[0]/2)
    return [number[0]/2]
```